# Send email after x days if payement not send

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8

After a purchase by bank transfer, i want to send an email 5 days later if the transfer has not been done yet.

How i can do this ?

Thank you for help

Comment: hi have you find the solution , if you found please post here , thanks